# Como duplicar os registros de uma tabela no BD

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Bom eu tenho um BD com alguns registros. E eu gostaria que essa quantidade de registros duplicasse. Não quero fazer loop duplo para mostrar a dupla quantidade, gostaria de literalmente duplicar todos os registros na tabela. Há alguma forma de realizar isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amigo faz um insert e nos values voce faz um select, assim:

```
INSERT INTO [Database].[dbo].[Table]
       ([Coluna1]
       ,[Coluna2])
 select Coluna1, Coluna2 from Table
GO
```

Isso vai duplicar sua tabela, pois ele vai  inserir tudo o que ja existe na sua tabela.

Espero que ajude. []'s

Answer (score 6):

Utilize um `insert` junto com um `select`, os tipos de dados no `select` e no `insert` devem ser os mesmos ou compativeis também é possivel utilizar outras clausulas como `where`, `join`etc

```
INSERT INTO tabela(c1, c2, c3) SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM tabela
```

[insert select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Deve ser colocado no lugar de c1 do SELECT, o valor Null se, somente se, c1 for a chave primaria do banco, senão haverá um erro ao tentar duplicar o id.